# Save json result of a function in javascript object

Tags: node.js, function, object, mongoose

I'm a beginner in nodejs and javascript and i try to make an application but i have problems. 
So I work with nodejs express and mongodb 
 and i have a function that has two parameters err and result.
The latter (result) is a json file which contains the following elemennts (title, URL, description, publishdAt, King, etage, id ....).
What I'm looking for is to create an object and save just the four elements (title, URL, description, publishdAt) in this object.
I created a database(Videos), a schema(videoSchema) and a collection(collectionVideos),

This my code:

```
youTube.search(Query, 5, function(error, result) {

            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
            } else {
                var convertedToJson = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2)
                console.log(convertedToJson);

                a = convertedToJson.title
                b = convertedToJson.url
                c = convertedToJson.descriptionb
                d = convertedToJson.publishedAt
                post = new videosNews({
                    "title": a,
                    "url": b,
                    "description": c,
                    "publishedAt": d
                })
                console.log(post)
                post.save(function(err, data) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log('rong')
                    } else {
                        console.log('save')
                    }
                })
            })
```

this code does not generate any error but the object is not created
And this is the result of my console.log:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5T2q.png)
thank you in advance

Comment: `JSON.stringify` converts a JSON Object to plain text. Therefore, `convertedToJson.title`, `convertedToJson.url` etc... will not work.

Comment: ok thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

First, remove the `stringify` function. you don't need it.

Also note that the elements you want are not in the root level of the result, but they are under the `items` array of objects, under the `snippet` property.

The following example takes just the first item.

```js
youTube.search(Query, 5, function(error, result) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    var snippet = result.items[0].snippet;
    post = new videosNews ({
      title: snippet.title,
      url: snippet.url,
      description: snippet.description,
      publishedAt: snippet.publishedAt
    })
    console.log(post)
    post.save(function(err, data) {
      if(err){console.log('rong')}
      else {console.log('save')}
    })
  }
})
```

If you know there is more than one item in the `items` array, then consider looping through the array and save each item separately

Comment: thank you so much for your feedback  I tried what you proposed to me but the object is not created. Can you please see the image attached to my question that shows the structure of my json file

Comment: Updated answer. Please try again